# Enumerar el numero de registros en Java

Tags: java, loops, ciclos

¿Como puedo enumerar el numero de registros que salen en un programa? Se supone que el usuario ingresa el numero de registros que desea, una ves realizado esto salen los datos pero necesitan salir enumerados.

```
import java.util.*;
public class practica1Laboratorio{
    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner entrada;
        entrada=new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);


        Scanner entrada2;
        entrada2=new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] nombre=new String[6];
        int[] sexo= new int[6];
        int[] edad= new int[6];
        int[] nacionalidad=new int[6];

        int x=0,c=0,menor=0,mayor=0,thombre=0,tmujer=0,tmex=0,text=0,tregistros=0,tmayores=0,tmenores=0,op,top=0,numero=0; 

        do{
            System.out.println("Cuantos registros deseas: ");
            op=entrada2.nextInt();
            int[] valores=new int[op];
            top=top+1;
            if(op>5)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
        while (op>5);
        for(x=0; x<op; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre");
            nombre[x]=sc.nextLine();
            do{
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu edad");
                edad[x]=entrada.nextInt();
                if(edad[x]>102)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                if(edad[x]>18)
                {
                    tmayores=tmayores+1;
                }
                if(edad[x]<18)
                {
                    tmenores=tmenores+1;
                }
            }
            while (edad[x]>102);
            do{
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu sexo: 1.Mujer 2.Hombre");
                sexo[x]=entrada.nextInt();
                if (sexo[x]>2){
                   System.out.println("Error");
                }
                if(sexo[x]==1)
                {tmujer=tmujer+1;
                }
                if(sexo[x]==2)
                 {
                thombre=thombre+1;
                }
            }while (sexo[x]>2);
            do{ 
                System.out.println("Ingresa tu nacionalidad: 1.Mexicano 2.Extranjero");
                nacionalidad[x]=entrada.nextInt();
                if(nacionalidad[x]>2){
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                if(nacionalidad[x]==1)
                {
                    tmex=tmex+1;
                }
                if(nacionalidad[x]==2)
                {
                    text=text+1;
                } 
            }
            while (nacionalidad[x]>2);
        }
        for(x=0; x<6; x++)
        {
            if (edad[x]<=18 &&sexo[x]==1 &&nacionalidad[x]==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre[x].toUpperCase()+" Edad: "+ edad[x]+" Eres menor de edad Sexo:Mujer Nacionalidad: Mexicana ");
            }
            if (edad[x]<=18 &&sexo[x]==1 &&nacionalidad[x]==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre[x].toUpperCase()+" Edad: "+ edad[x]+" Eres menor de edad Sexo:Mujer Nacionalidad: Extranjera ");
            }
            if(edad[x]<=18 &&sexo[x]==2 &&nacionalidad[x]==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " +nombre[x].toUpperCase()+" Edad: "+edad[x]+" Eres menor de edad Sexo:Hombre Nacionalidad: Mexicana");
            }
            if(edad[x]<=18 &&sexo[x]==2 &&nacionalidad[x]==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " +nombre[x].toUpperCase()+" Edad: "+edad[x]+" Eres menor de edad Sexo:Hombre Nacionalidad: Extranjera");
            }
            if(edad[x]>=18 &&sexo[x]==1 && nacionalidad[x]==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " +nombre[x].toUpperCase()+ " Edad: "+edad[x]+" Eres mayor de edad Sexo:Mujer Nacionalidad: Mexicana");
            }
            if(edad[x]>=18 &&sexo[x]==1 && nacionalidad[x]==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " +nombre[x].toUpperCase()+ " Edad: "+edad[x]+" Eres mayor de edad Sexo:Mujer Nacionalidad: Extranjera");
            }
            if(edad[x]>=18 &&sexo[x]==2 && nacionalidad[x]==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre[x]+" Edad:"+edad[x]+" Eres mayor de edad Sexo:Hombre Nacionalidad: Mexicana");
            }
            if(edad[x]>=18 &&sexo[x]==2 && nacionalidad[x]==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre[x]+" Edad:"+edad[x]+" Eres mayor de edad Sexo:Hombre Nacionalidad: Extranjera");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total de registros: "+top);
        System.out.println("Total de mujeres: "+tmujer);
        System.out.println("Total de hombres: "+thombre);
        System.out.println("Total de Mexicanos: "+tmex);
        System.out.println("Total de Extranjeros: "+text);
        System.out.println("Total de Mayores de Edad: "+tmayores);
        System.out.println("Total de Menores de Edad: " +tmenores);
        System.out.println("Stephanie B. Orihuela");
    }
}
```

Comment: Si me permites un consejo rápido, nunca hagas declaraciones multiples en una linea. 'int x=0,c=0,menor=0,mayor=0...'  Haz cada una en una nueva linea, queda mucho mas claro, facil de leer el código y de debugear en caso de errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se muy bien que quieres enumerar, entiendo que es la salida de tu programa.

Ya que imprimes los mensajes en un bucle for aprovechalo para enumerar.

```
System.out.println((x+1) + " Nombre: "+ nombre[x].toUpperCase()+" Edad: "+ edad[x]+" Eres menor de edad Sexo:Mujer Nacionalidad: Mexicana ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!